# UserInputFormat Class in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Please help me how to create UserInputFormat Class in mapreduce to produce key value pair based upon my need.I need to store the first character of the string as a key and the entire string as valuw. how to achieve it

Comment: Please add details of what you have tried, what is the input, its format, and what is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class UserInputFormat extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{ //define datatype of key:value = Text:Text
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String raw_String = value.toString(); 
  if (raw_String.length() > 0)
  {
        Text key_str = new Text(raw_String.substring(0, 1)); //get the first char of raw_String as key
          context.write(key_str, value); //key is the first character and value is the entire string
  }
}
}
```

I think the above is what you need. It is a map task, will receive a string as input, and will output a pair of key:value -> [1stchar]:[entire string].
If not please make your question clearer.

Comment: A small improvement to the code above, it is recommended to reuse Text objects and not to create them inside map method, just to reduce the load on the GC.  Declare them as class fields.